# return the value if its in within the range?

Tags: excel, vba

n this project i have to check column's A value between Column B and Column C. If columnA's values>= Columns B value or Columns A value<= Columns C value then i need to copy column d and e values and need to put into sheet1 column G and H. Column A is in sheet1 and Column B, C, D and E in sheet2.

```
   A       B    C   D     E
   1       1    9   Dog   Naruto
  11      10   19   Cat   one piece
  21      20   30   Duck  lo 
  1
  31
  12
  and so on
```

I want the outcome like this

```
   A    G       H
   1    Dog     Naruto   
   11   cat     One piece
   21   duck     o
   1    Dog     Naruto  
   31                   
   12   cat     One piece
   and so on
```

This is the code I got with the help of someone but its limited. I want it to return value no matter how many rows A column has.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim colA As Double, colB As Double, colC As Double

lRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & 
         Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lRow
    colA = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    colB = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value
    colC = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value

    If colA >= colB Or colA <= colC Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & 
   i).Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & 
  i).Value
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: The outcome does't fit your original data at all. `31` and `12` magically appear and some others magically disappeared. Why? Please be consistent in your data otherwise we are unable to understand what you are doing. Reading [MCVE] might help here.

Comment: my bad corrected it bro. In my A column i have around 1000 values. most of them are in within the range of  B and C column and some are not. If its in within the B and C column then i need to return D and E column in sheet1 G and H column. I hope it makes sense. Sorry again

Comment: Are the values in B and C always  ordered continous like you showed in the example? like `1 to 9` … `10 to 19` … `20 to 30` or are they ordered randomly? • A continous order would make it much easier.

Comment: 1   29
   30   60
   61   99
100 129
130 199
200 219
220 299
300 399
400 499
500 599
600 699
700 799
800 899
900 900

this is the actual pattern. i am new to vba and forcefully doing it for my work

Comment: Then see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If column B in `Sheet2` is in a ascending order …

[image]

… you can easily do that with a formula. In B2 add the following formula and pull it down and right.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH($A:$A,Sheet2!$B:$B,1))
```

And you will get this output in `Sheet1`:

[image]

The same approach would be possible with VBA using `Application.WorksheetFunction` but I recommend to use the formula.

#### VBA Solution

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindAndFillData()
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim wsLookup As Worksheet
    Set wsLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim MatchedRow As Double

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow
        MatchedRow = 0 'initialize!
        On Error Resume Next
        MatchedRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(wsDest.Cells(iRow, "A").Value, wsLookup.Columns("B"), 1)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If MatchedRow <> 0 Then
            If wsDest.Cells(iRow, "A").Value <= wsLookup.Cells(MatchedRow, "C").Value Then
                wsDest.Cells(iRow, "B").Value = wsLookup.Cells(MatchedRow, "D").Value
                wsDest.Cells(iRow, "C").Value = wsLookup.Cells(MatchedRow, "E").Value
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah i know. however my luck is bad bro and i was asked to do it with vba

Comment: There is no reason to do it with VBA. Actually VBA would only make it slower. Formulas are Excel's strenght! • Note that you can also write a formula with VBA like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C" & lRow).Formula="=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH($A:$A,Sheet2!$B:$B,1))"` if you need to use the formula in an automated process.

Comment: i told my boss several times but he wants me to do it in vba. Oh i guess you misunderstood my comment. i am not trying to use match function.For example If Column A>= Column B or ColumnA<=Column C then return column D and E value.

Comment: But I recommend using `WorksheetFunction.Match` because this will be *much* faster than looping through all the data in sheet2 for each row in sheet1. Especially because you told you have a lot of data.

Comment: i am well aware of that. and the moment i saw the data from my boss i told him the same work. I used to do data analysis in R. it was so much fun. and now in In vba i am having the most toughest time

Comment: So why don't you use `WorksheetFunction.Match` in VBA?

Comment: does not match function only look for the match?
what about a value which is 6 but the value between B and C is 1-10?

Comment: if you use the Match_type parameter as 1 it finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match)

Comment: Match would work if the lookup array is sorted, but it doesn't seem to be in the sample.